# Can you provide an example in relation to Hidden Field Equations Multivariate?

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, reference-request, finite-field

I'm reading about Hidden Field Equations Multivariate scheme. My lecture states that the central map is a univariate polynomial $$P(X)=\sum_{i=0}^{r-1}\sum_{j=0}^{r-1}p_{ij}x^{q^i+q^j} \in K[X]$$ where $K$ is a extension field of the finite field $k=\mathbb{F}_q$ of degree $n$ and $r$ is a small constant chosen in a way such that $P(x)$ can efficiently inverted.

> $r$ is a small constant chosen in a way such that $P(x)$ can efficiently inverted.

I would like an example about the last claim please.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. The question you appear to be asking can be answered by saying "Let $r=1$", which is surely not what you mean.

Comment: I edit my question

Comment: When $r$ is small, the degree of $P$ is at most $2q^{r-1}$. We assume this value is small. You can find several algorithms to find the root of P in **textbooks on computer algebra** or find **programs** implementing them; sage, pari, and so on.